# not able to insert multi-line special characters data correctly

Tags: data-loader, data-export, data-migration, language

My problem scenario is like this: 
I have to migrate chatter data from a Japan org to my PROD org. The Japan org has all chatter data (CollaborationGroup, FeedItem & FeedComment) in Japanese language and I have tried the following way to export data but unable to insert multi-line data correctly:
1. Pulled a report for say (chatter group) with Encoding 'UTF-8' export type 'Excel or. csv', after exporting correctly I am able to dump that in *unicode text* and then *.csv with unicode - UTF-08*.
2. Pulled a Data-Export with **checked - replace return carriage with spaces** and then dumped into .csv with UTF-08 file format.

In both the method I am able to insert my multi-line text in **one single line only** and as the language is Japanese all inserted text looks more like a junk.

This is how it appears:

> **Correct Format**
>  
>   ＜入力する内容＞
>  
>   ・コマーシャルオペレーション部からITへの依頼（現場ユーザーからの要望も含めます）
>  
>   ・ユーザーからの要望でコマーシャルオペレーションで自己完結した案件も含めます。
>
> ＜対応の方法についてお願い＞
>  
>   ・完成日の回答（予定）をお願いいたします。
>  
>   　-トラブル対応にて遅れる場合にもコメントをお願いいたします。
>  
>   ・対応が完了しましたら対応済のコメントをお願いいたします。
>  
>   ・ITからコマーシャルオペレーションで対応できると思われるものはその旨コメントください。
>  
>  
>   メールでの依頼を極力減らしこのグループへ投稿します（緊急対応の場合を除く）
>   
>  
>  
>   **After Insertion**
>  
>   ＜入力する内容＞
>   ・コマーシャルオペレーション部からITへの依頼（現場ユーザーからの要望も含めます）
>   ・ユーザーからの要望でコマーシャルオペレーションで自己完結した案件も含めます。
>   ＜対応の方法についてお願い＞
>   ・完成日の回答（予定）をお願いいたします。
>   　-トラブル対応にて遅れる場合にもコメントをお願いいたします。
>   ・対応が完了しましたら対応済のコメントをお願いいたします。
>   ・ITからコマーシャルオペレーションで対応できると思われるものはその旨コメントください。
>   メールでの依頼を極力減らしこのグループへ投稿します（緊急対応の場合を除く）

Is there any way to through which I can insert my Japanese language multi-line text correctly Into my PROD org.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Chirag

Comment: Try without "replace return carriage with spaces" - it's pretty obvious it'll combine multiple lines into one :/ Reports might have same problem. Try exporting within Data Loader itself and check whether CSV file does contain multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, I am presently exporting with this option 'unchecked'. And while extracting through data-loader these multi-line Japanese text got splitted into adjacent rows that will make it more worse.

Comment: It will appear to be split but the field boundaries should be determined by quote marks: "some value","text with newlines","another field's value". So it should import back OK.

Comment: Right, using MSFT Excel to view CSV data can sometimes be misleading when dealing with UTF-8 and non A-Z,a-z,0-9. Notepad++ or even the browser using UTF-8 encoding gives a truer picture of the real bytes and placement of the line breaks

Comment: Hey, I am taking an Data-Export again can you help me choose **Encoding File** format. I am only extracting Chatter Related data now that contains Japanese Character's. Previously I have selected *UTF-08*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to load multi-line special character's data (say Japanese language) correctly as it was originally in their formatting. So what I have done is:
1. Uses a *Data-Export* feature to export all the records(having multi-line special charac) pertaining to any Standard/Custom objects with this CHECKBOX unchecked **"Replace Return Carriage with Spaces"**.
2. Once the Data-Export is available, I just open the Exported .csv files directly by *double clicking* with Excel (ver. 2003 used in mine case); Once it is opened I do the required changes in various column for adding Id or updating **without touching the columns with special character's** and just saving in the same format by just clicking on *save* button.
3. Once the File is saved just load it through Data-Loader or Workbench & you will get your special character's data loaded in correct format. :)

In this way the *Return Carriages* also know as **char(10) in Excel** is preserved and the multi-line special character text got loaded correctly.

Also I have noticed that if the field in which we are inserting the *multi-line special character* is **textarea** then it will perfectly accept the Return Carriage *or* char(10) - said in Excel But if any-other field type like e.g. 'text' then it will not accept any new line character's.

Thanks!

Chirag